# How to debug a 500 can't load error?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, debug, error-reporting

I have moved a website running joomla from my old VPS to my own server.  The server is working fine, other sites are loading.  However, this joomla site doesn't load.

Please can someone explain what php debugging code that I need to put in the index.php file so that I can get some feedback as to why it's falling over.

Thanks in advance
Vince.

Comment: How did you migrate the site over? Manually or using something like Akeeba Backup/Kickstart? Have you created your database on the new server? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I manually moved all the files.  Did an export / import of the database changed the ownership of the files to www-server or whatever you are supposed to, and chmod'd the permissions.  I simply get a 500 can't load error message.  Looking for some debug code to put into the index.php

Comment: Have you tried the "Debug System" option in Global Configuration?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are going to move the site to another one, I highly recommend you to use Akeeba Backup.

There is a free version and it would make moving your website a lot simpler, while reducing the possibilities of a number of issues/errors compared to when moving your site manually.

At the hand, open your configuration.php and check everything it's ok with the new site configuration.

I think you can put the system on development state from the configuration.php, but I'm sorry that I can't provide more help in this issue.

If you continue to have the original deploy alive, I highly reccomend you to use Akeeba Backup and then try again (installing it into your server).

Comment: You can backup a site, when it's live and working, but if your VPS provider webfusion broke your site, and then told you that they do not offer to help, even though the site crashed due to their infrastructure, you're pretty much screwed.  I grabbed all I could, even though it wouldn't load, and neither did any other sites I had, but these "wordpress" sites have been restored and are now working, It's just this Joomla one that I am struggling with.

Comment: @VincentGledhill - In such cases, I strongly recommend to hire someone to help you - as the sooner you do so without messing a lot with the rescued files/databases, the more the chances are to have your site survive.